# How to find $\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}\frac1{(k+a)(k+b)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Let $a,b$ be two unequal integers. I have to find the sum below.
$$
\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}\frac1{(k+a)(k+b)}
$$
I should use complex analysis, but I have no clue where to start. I only now that I can assume without loss of generality that $a = 0$ because $x \mapsto x -a$ is an invertible map on the set of integers. I would like to get I hint from you, *just* a hint.

Comment: I think you want the sum for $k\in \mathbb{Z}\setminus\{-a,-b\}$.

Comment: Or $k, a, b \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: k should not equal -a or -b

Answer (score 6):

Can you find $A$ and $B$ for which $$\frac{1}{(k+a)(k+b)}=\frac{A}{k+a}+\frac{B}{k+b}$$

Answer (score 3):

If $b\gt a$, then
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{\substack{k\in\mathbb{Z}\\k\not\in\{-a,-b\}}}\frac1{(k+a)(k+b)}
&=\frac1{b-a}\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{\substack{k=-n\\k\not\in\{-a,-b\}}}^n\left(\frac1{k+a}-\frac1{k+b}\right)\\
&=\frac1{b-a}\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{\substack{k=-n+a\\k\not\in\{0,a-b\}}}^{n+a}\frac1k-\sum_{\substack{k=-n+b\\k\not\in\{0,b-a\}}}^{n+b}\frac1k\right)\\
&=\frac1{b-a}\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{\substack{k=-n+a\\k\ne0}}^{n+a}\frac1k-\sum_{\substack{k=-n+b\\k\ne0}}^{n+b}\frac1k+\frac2{b-a}\right)\\
&=\frac1{b-a}\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=-n+a}^{-n+b-1}\frac1k-\sum_{k=n+a-1}^{n+b}\frac1k+\frac2{b-a}\right)\\[9pt]
&=\frac2{(b-a)^2}
\end{align}
$$
Switching $a$ and $b$ gives the same result for $b\lt a$.

If $a=b$, then
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{\substack{k\in\mathbb{Z}\\k\ne-a}}\frac1{(k+a)^2}
&=\sum_{\substack{k\in\mathbb{Z}\\k\ne0}}\frac1{k^2}\\
&=2\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^2}\\[6pt]
&=\frac{\pi^2}{3}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

*I dropped the spoiler markup, as too many open answers have been posted already.*

**Hint 2:**

*Like fellow user Michael sugggested, a decomposition helps.*

Using [partial fraction decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition):
$$
1 = (k+b) A + (k+a) B = (A + B) k + b A + a B \iff \\A = -B \wedge (b-a) A = 1 \iff \\A = \frac{1}{b - a} \wedge B = \frac{1}{a - b}
$$

for $a \ne b$.

**Hint 3:**

*Note the task asks for $a, b \in \mathbb{N}$ and $a \ne b$.*

Now looking at the basic sums:
$$
\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{-a \}} \frac{1}{k+a} =^{(*)} \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{ 0 \}} \frac{1}{k} =^{(**)} 0 \Rightarrow\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{ -a, -b \}} \frac{1}{k+a} = 0 - \frac{1}{-b+a} = \frac{1}{b-a}
$$

**Caution:**

*Fellow user Thomas Andrews raised concerns, that the index transformation in equation $(*)$ might not be valid. And I assumed in equation $(**)$ that terms $\frac{1}{k}$ and $-\frac{1}{k}$ cancel out pairwise, but that might be too naive as well.*

**Proof attempt:** I assumed 
$$
\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}\setminus \{-a\}}\frac{1}{k+a} = \lim_{N\to\infty} S_N
$$

with 
$$
S_N = \sum_{k=-N}^{-a-1}\frac{1}{k+a}+\sum_{-a+1}^N\frac{1}{k+a}
$$

We have 
$$
S_N = \sum_{k=-N+a}^{-1}\frac{1}{k}+\sum_{k=1}^{N+a}\frac{1}{k}=\sum_{k=1}^{N-a}-\frac{1}{k}+\sum_{k=1}^{N+a}\frac{1}{k}=\sum_{k=N-a+1}^{N+a}\frac{1}{k}=\sum_{k=1}^{2a}\frac{1}{N-a+k}
$$

and for $N>a$ (and $a \in \mathbb{N}$) we get 
$$ 
0 < S_N < \frac{2a}{N-a},
$$

so $S_N$ will vanish for $N \to \infty$.

**Solution:**

The above leads to 
$$
\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{ -a, -b \}} \frac{1}{(k+a)(k+b)} =\frac{1}{(b-a)^2} + \frac{1}{(a-b)^2}=\frac{2}{(a-b)^2}
$$

for $a \ne b$.

BTW, the case $a = b$ boils down to
$$
\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}\setminus \{a\}}\frac{1}{(k+a)^2} = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}\setminus \{0\}}\frac{1}{k^2} = 2 \sum_{k = 1}^\infty\frac{1}{k^2} = 2 \, \zeta(2) = \frac{\pi^2}{3}
$$
using $\zeta(2)$, see [A013661](http://oeis.org/A013661).

Comment: You can't say $\sum_{k\in \mathbb Z\setminus-a} f(k+a)=\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z\setminus 0} f(k)$ unless the sum is absolutely convergent, in general, I believe.

Comment: I cant read your answer

Answer (score 1):

**Too long for a comment** : In general, $~\displaystyle\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}\frac1{(k+a)(k+b)}~=~-\pi\cdot\frac{\cot(a\pi)-\cot(b\pi)}{a-b}$

- For $a=b\not\in\mathbb Z$, this becomes $\bigg[\dfrac\pi{\sin(\pi a)}\bigg]^2$
- For $a=b\in\mathbb Z$, upon eliminating the problematic term $k=-a$, this becomes $2~\zeta(2)=\dfrac{\pi^2}3$
- For $a\in\mathbb Z$ and $b\not\in\mathbb Z$, upon eliminating the problematic term $k=-a$, this becomes $\dfrac1{(a-b)^2}+\dfrac{\pi\cdot\cot(b\pi)}{a-b}$
- For $a\neq b$ integers, upon eliminating the problematic terms $k=-a$ and $k=-b$, this becomes $\dfrac2{(a-b)^2}$

Unfortunately, the only ways in which I personally am able to prove any of this is by manipulating Euler's [infinite product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem#Examples_of_factorization) formulas for the sine and cosine functions, as well as his integral expression for generalized [harmonic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Calculation), along with some good, old fashioned [l'Hopital](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L'Hopital's_rule).

Answer (score 1):

Consider this an addition to Lucian's post.

It can be shown that the quantity

$$\lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{k = -N}^{k = N} f(k)$$

is equal to the negative of the sum of the residues of $\pi f(z) \cot(\pi z)$ at the poles of $f(z)$. This is the case when $f(z)$ is a rational function of the form $P(z)/Q(z)$ where the degree of $Q$ is greater than or equal to twice the degree of $P$. It also must be that $f$ has no poles on the integers.

In your case, $f(z) = \frac1{(z+a)(z+b)}$ so that the poles are just at $-a$ and $-b$.

This means that

$$\begin{align}\lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{k = -N}^{k = N} \frac1{(k+a)(k+b)} &=  -\left(\lim_{z\to -a} \frac{(z+a)\pi\cot(\pi z)}{(z+a)(z+b)} + \lim_{z\to -b} \frac{(z+b)\pi\cot(\pi z)}{(z+a)(z+b)}\right) \\&= -\lim_{z\to -a} \frac{\pi\cot(\pi z)}{(z+b)} + \lim_{z\to -b} \frac{\pi\cot(\pi z)}{(z+a)}\\&= -\frac{\pi\cot(a\pi )}{a-b}  - \frac{\pi\cot(b\pi)}{a-b}\\&= -\pi\left(\frac{\cot(a\pi)-\cot(b\pi)}{a-b}\right)\end{align}$$

---

I will outline a proof of my first statement but will not show all of the steps.

First, show that $$\operatorname{Res}(\pi f(z)\cot(\pi z),k) = f(k), \;k \in \mathbb{Z}$$

Construct a square contour $\Gamma_N$ with verticies at $(N+1/2)(1+i)$, $(N+1/2)(-1+i)$, $(N+1/2)(-1-i)$ and $(N+1/2)(-1-i)$ in that order. Now show that $|\pi\cot(\pi z)|$ is bounded along this contour.

Using this, prove that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{\Gamma_N}\! \pi f(z)\cot(\pi z)\, \mathrm{d}z = 0$$

The end result is a simple application of the residue theorem.

Comment: If $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$, then $\cot(a\pi)$ and $\cot(b\pi)$ are undefined.