# Speeding up the convergence of a series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, maxima-software

I want to speed up the convergence of a series involving rational expressions the expression is $$\sum _{x=1}^{\infty }\left( -1\right) ^{x}\dfrac {-x^{2}-2x+1} {x^{4}+2x^{2}+1}$$
If I have not misunderstood anything the error in the infinite sum is at most the absolute value of the last neglected term. The formula for the $n$th term is $\dfrac {-x^{2}-2x+1} {x^{4}+2x^{2}+1}$ from the definition of the series. To get the series I used Maxima the computer algebra system. I have noticed that to get 13 decimal places of the series one must wade through $312958$ terms of the series. I had to kill the computer GUI and some other system processes and run Maxima to compute the sum. I took about 5 minutes. The final sum I obtained was $0.3106137076850$. Is there any way to speed up the convergence of the sum? In general is there any way to speed up the convergence of the sum of $$\sum _{x=1}^{\infty }\left( -1\right) ^{x}\dfrac {p(x)} {q(x)}$$

where both ${p(x)}$ and ${q(x)}$ are rational functions?

Comment: Out of curiosity, where does the sequence come from?  (Normally it would be written with 'n' instead of 'x', FWIW, but that's a tiny thing.)  The value of this sequence can probably be found explicitly using digamma functions, but presumably you're not particularly interested in that?

Comment: As far as convergence speedup goes, you _may_ be able to use Euler's transform ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_acceleration#Euler.27s_transform ) to convert the series; it would take finding a good formula for the $k$'th difference of terms, but that may be feasible.

Comment: This sequence came out of a series derivative problem, x is my favorite variable and I tend to use it in place of a lot of thing even when I should not. And no matter how nightmarish I still want to find a closed in solution in terms of digamma functions if needed.

Comment: Consider partial fractions. If you choose, you can write $$\sum _{x=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^x}{x^2+1} = \frac{1}{2} (1+\pi  \text{csch}(\pi ))$$

Comment: Hyperbolic cosecant. It would have to be derived with complex methods. Consider the approach in [my post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/863174/how-to-find-sum-k-in-mathbbz-frac1kakb/863579#863579) here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several methods to speed up the summation of series.  For example [Euler summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_summation) or the [Shanks transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shanks_transformation).  Here is a simple method that works quite well. Let $$f(n)=\frac{n^2+2n-1}{n^4+2n^2+1}$$ and $$g(n)=\tfrac{1}{2}f(2n-1)-f(2n)+\tfrac{1}{2}f(2n+1).$$  Then $$f(1)-f(2)+f(3)-\ldots = \tfrac{1}{2}f(1) +g(1)+g(2)+g(3)+\ldots$$ but the right hand side converges much faster than the left hand side.  This is a generic method.  For example if you take $$f(n)=\frac{1}{n}$$ then $$g(n)=\frac{1}{(2n-1)\cdot 2n \cdot (2n+1)}$$ and $$\log(2)=1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\ldots =\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{1\cdot 2\cdot 3} + \frac{1}{3\cdot 4 \cdot 5}+\ldots$$

Comment: What is this method called?

Comment: @Sumo I don't know.  You could call it "truncated Euler summation".  It is one of a whole family of methods, each one converging faster.  It is interesting stuff!

Comment: @Sumo it can indeed be thought of as a truncated Euler summation as per my new answer. In particular, this is $S_n^{(2)}$.

Comment: Are you using Shanks for Eulers in your examples? I think maybe Euler, but I dont see a direct translation from the article to your example. Where did the alternatingness go?  Shouldnt it be $f(n)=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$? What value of y are you using in Euler? Whats this bit about truncating?  Are you arbitrarily truncating? Which series: the inner one or the outer one?  Wheres the binary coefficient?  Honestly youve provided very little explanation and havent even written the explicit theorem youre using.

Comment: Also in your first example you seem to be combining terms of $f(n)$ into a term of $g(n)$. Doesnt this require non-conditional convergence to hold?  What assumptions about the series are being made?

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum As I state in my previous comment, this is a "truncated Euler acceleration". You can check my answer for more details.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I did read your answer... you clearly said "euler summation or shanks transformation". I asked you which it was.  You seem to think that your comments constitute a part of the answer. Why dont you specify what youre doing in the body of your answer and not in some side conversation you expect everyone to keep up on.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum There is no mention of Shank's transformation/method in my answer below as far as I can see?

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum As far as mentioning comments, my answer explicitly says that these are mentioned in other comments and answers? I think it is pretty clear that my answer is supposed to explain the Euler transform in more detail, it's not clear to me what you are talking about.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the first step toward making the series evaluate quicker. You may need just as many terms but it will be faster. Break the series up through partial fractions.

$$\dfrac {-x^{2}-2x+1} {x^{4}+2x^{2}+1} = -\frac{2 (x-1)}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2}-\frac{1}{x^2+1}$$

I will focus on the second term in the sum.

$$\sum_{x=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^x}{x^2+1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{4n^2+1} - \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k+1)^2+1}$$

Each of the two sums can be evaluated by contour methods. This approach can be found in my post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/863174/how-to-find-sum-k-in-mathbbz-frac1kakb/863579#863579). In short, for a sufficient rational function $f(z)$,

$$\lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{k = -N}^{k = N} f(k)$$

is equal to the negative of the sum of the residues of $\pi f(z) \cot(\pi z)$ at the poles of $f(z)$. We can use this because we are summing an even function. This yields

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{4n^2+1} = \frac{1}{4} \left(2+\pi  \coth \left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)\right)$$

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k+1)^2+1} = \frac{1}{4} \pi  \tanh \left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)$$

Subtract these (and simplify) to find

$$\sum_{x=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^x}{x^2+1} = \frac{1}{2} (\pi  \operatorname{csch}(\pi )-1)$$

Now we can conclude our first step by writing...

$$\sum _{x=1}^{\infty }\left( -1\right) ^{x}\dfrac {-x^{2}-2x+1} {x^{4}+2x^{2}+1} = -\frac{1}{2} (\pi  \operatorname{csch}(\pi )-1) - \sum_{x=1}^\infty(-1)^x\frac{2 (x-1)}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2}$$

It may be tempting to try the same approach for the remaining series but we are not summing an even function so it will not be as easy.

Comment: If you are just looking for the numerical value I'm sure someone could provide it for you with as many digits as you need.

Comment: One thing that's worth noting: the last summand does have an even part, and that can be approached in the same manner as Brad does above. It's the last summation of $\sum_{x=0}^\infty (-1)^{k-1}x(x^2+1)^{-2}$ that's problematic (the digamma terms are all in there). @Sumo

Comment: I love you guys, thank you for being so supportive! However I still want to know a general approach to the second part of my problem, which is the general one involving rational functions. I am willing to give a upvote but as of now it is not the final answer, as it has not given a solution or lack thereof the second part, sorry if I am too demanding.

Comment: @Brad. I think that your last summation starts at $x=1$.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For the summation $$S=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\left( -1\right) ^{n}\dfrac {-n^{2}-2n+1} {n^{4}+2n^{2}+1}$$ a CAS gave as a result $$\frac{1}{8} \left(2 \pi ^2 \text{csch}^2\left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)+(1-i) \left(\psi
   ^{(1)}\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2}\right)+i \left((-4+4 i)+\psi
   ^{(1)}\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right)+\psi
   ^{(1)}\left(1-\frac{i}{2}\right)\right)+\psi
   ^{(1)}\left(1+\frac{i}{2}\right)\right)\right)$$ which is approximately $0.31061370769015654201991515962234635408157816305055$ (this could be computed for as many significant figures as required).

Considering Brad's result, for

$$T=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{2 (n-1)}{\left(n^2+1\right)^2}$$ a CAS gave $$\left(-\frac{1}{8}+\frac{i}{8}\right) \left((2+2 i)+(1+i) \pi  \left(\pi 
   \text{csch}^2\left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)+2 \text{csch}(\pi )\right)+\psi
   ^{(1)}\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2}\right)+i \psi
   ^{(1)}\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right)+i \psi
   ^{(1)}\left(1-\frac{i}{2}\right)+\psi ^{(1)}\left(1+\frac{i}{2}\right)\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

This implementation of Euler's acceleration method is apparently known as [Van Wijngaarden's transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Wijngaarden_transformation).

Euler's acceleration method, as mentioned in the comments and in other answers, can speed up the convergence of an alternating series. It is easy to look at it in terms of a more general sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ which oscillates around it's limit. If this happens, then the limit may be more accurately estimated by $(b_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ defined by

$$b_n=\frac{a_n+a_{n+1}}2$$

since the limit should be between consecutive terms. In the case of partial sums of alternating rational functions, this new averaged sequence will also oscillate around it's limit, so taking the average $(b_n+b_{n+1})/2$ will increase the convergence again. The limit as the amount of averaging we've done tends to infinity gives us Euler's acceleration method, though it may be more suitable to simply stop at averaging 10 times.

As far as coding this, it is very easy. Simply compute the partial sums and then average backwards until satisfied.

Let $S_n^{(m)}$ be the $n$th term after averaging $m$ times. Then you can compute it like so:

\begin{array}{c}S_0^{(0)}&&S_1^{(0)}&&S_2^{(0)}&&S_3^{(0)}&&S_4^{(0)}&\cdots\\\downarrow&\swarrow&\downarrow&\swarrow&\downarrow&\swarrow&\downarrow&\swarrow&\cdots\\S_0^{(1)}&&S_1^{(1)}&&S_2^{(1)}&&S_3^{(1)}&\cdots\\\downarrow&\swarrow&\downarrow&\swarrow&\downarrow&\swarrow&\cdots\\S_0^{(2)}&&S_1^{(2)}&&S_2^{(2)}&\cdots\\\downarrow&\swarrow&\downarrow&\swarrow&\cdots\\S_0^{(3)}&&S_1^{(3)}&\cdots\\\downarrow&\swarrow&\cdots\\S_0^{(4)}&\dots\end{array}